# \listoffigures not doing multiple lines?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to sort out why \listoffigures would not wrap for multiple lines.  Attached is an example of my rendered figure list, where the second entry will go off the page. Is there a flag somewhere that I have missed to be sure that the list of figures is multiple lines per entry?

Included is the code and a rendered image of what I see.  I am using:

> "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)"

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,left=1in,top=.4in,right=1in,bottom=.75in,headsep=\dimexpr3cm-59pt\relax,headheight=59pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pagebackref,hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

% default font packages
\usepackage{courier} % use courier for the mono-spaced font 
\usepackage{helvet}  % use a Helvetica clone for default text (sans-serif)

\begin{document}
\newpage
\listoffigures 

\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:blocks:first}}{\includegraphics[width=3.0in]{eps/testblocks.eps}} &
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:blocks:second}}{\includegraphics[width=3.0in]{eps/testblocks.eps}} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{short caption is okay}
\label{fig:blocks}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:blocks2:first}}{\includegraphics[width=3.0in]{eps/testblocks.eps}} &
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:blocks2:second}}{\includegraphics[width=3.0in]{eps/testblocks.eps}} \\
\end{tabular}

\caption{longer caption does not span multiples lines in the list of figures and instead runs off the page}
\label{fig:blocks2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik actually, that is the issue at hand.  I've used \listoffigures and I've never had an issue until I used it on a project with a template that I did not write.  I was unable to find a "switch" that might have turned off the multiple lines, and I was hoping that someone might have come up with this from the past.  The template is more than I strip out to make a minimally viable program.

Comment: But without the template it would require (for me, at least), a lot of guesswork to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Let me see what I can strip out and update the post.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I've edited the question to include what you asked.  I was actually better and worse than I feared, but I got it to show the same behavior.  I was still unable to debug what is causing the issue. :(

Comment: Sorry, but for me it works fine: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw9ge.png). @DavidCarlisle pointed out that my TeX distribution is outdated, so someone with a newer version will have to check...

Comment: We don't have your pictures so we can't reproduce what you get exactly. But I can't reproduce your problem, for me the caption is broken across the lines as expected in the lof.